# Why is this "illegal url" error appearing when running flutter doctor?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have installed a new version of flutter in my macOS. But when trying to run
`flutter doctor` I get this

```
Downloading Dart SDK from Flutter engine <<<<<<< HEAD
05e680e202af9a92461070cb2d9982acad46c83c
=======
d3ea636dc5d16b56819f3266241e1f708979c233
>>>>>>> 18116933e77adc82f80866c928266a5b4f1ed645...
curl: (3) URL using bad/illegal format or missing URL

Failed to retrieve the Dart SDK from: https://storage.googleapis.com/flutter_infra_release/flutter/<<<<<<< HEAD
05e680e202af9a92461070cb2d9982acad46c83c
=======
d3ea636dc5d16b56819f3266241e1f708979c233
>>>>>>> 18116933e77adc82f80866c928266a5b4f1ed645/dart-sdk-darwin-x64.zip
If you're located in China, please see this page:
  https://flutter.dev/community/china
```

Is there a known fix for this? I have looked for an answer, but they're mostly targeted towards Windows.

Comment: Looks like you have some git merge markers in there...

Comment: What should I do, run `git merge` in the flutter folder? @VincentRamdhanie

Comment: Well...you need to fix the syntax. Look at the file where this code is located and make sure that the code is valid.

Answer (score 0):

navigate to git folder

in git console: (be aware local changes are dismissed!)

> git fetch --all
>
> git reset --hard origin/master

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me -  deleted the flutter folder and replaced it with one from the official flutter webpage